# Traversal over last element of 'filtered'

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm looking to filter a traversal, then select the last element to use with `over`.

e.g. something like this (but which will actually compile):

```
[1,2,3,4] & traverse . filtered even . _last +~ 10
> [1,2,3,14]
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm aware that `filtered` is only valid when not affecting the number of elements in the traversal.

The actual use case I'm performing is to select only the lowest level of a recursive `uniplate` traversal that matches some predicate; if you have other ideas of how to do this I'd love to hear them!

Comment: I had a crack at doing this by traversing in the reverse state monad transformer, but that gives you a signature of `MonadFix m => Traversal' s a -> LensLike' m s a` which is not terribly useful - you can only put values into it, not get them out, because `Const s` is not a `Monad`. An alternative approach would be to get the length of the collection by folding and then count statefully up to the last index - that'd give you a `Monad` constraint instead of `MonadFix` at the expense of some efficiency. Going via a concrete list, as in @Gurkenglas's answer, is probably your best bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, just a follow-up to @Gurkenglas that's too big for a comment.  Note that @Gurkenglas's answer:

```
let t = partsOf (traverse . filtered even) . _last
```

may *look* like a Traversal, but it isn't, even if you maintain the element count, because it violates the second Traversal law (for obvious reasons):

```
let f = Identity . succ
[1,2,3,4] & fmap (t f) . t f  -- yields [1,3,3,5] effectively
[1,2,3,4] & getCompose . t (Compose . fmap f . f)
                              -- yields [1,2,3,6] effectively
```

For it to be a traversal, you have to maintain *both* the element count *and* the filtering property as invariants.

Whether this will matter for your application, I don't know, but just be aware that `partsOf` comes with these sorts of caveats, and the documentation misleadingly suggests that the result of `partsOf` will be a Lens if you maintain the element count.  (That's true for `partsOf each`, the example given in the documentation, but not in general.)

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3,4] & partsOf (traverse . filtered even) . _last +~ 10
```